# Generate code documentation to a MS Word file

Tags: visual-studio, ms-word, documentation

I would like to generate code documentation (C#, .net4) to MS Word file (.doc, .docx). This is not because I think it is better, but because it is easier to version control when compared to a set of HTML docs.

I am looking into the possibility and practicality of this and weighing the options.

I see doxygen can produce RTF documents. There is nothing wrong with doxygen, I just want to know if there is anything else out there (paid or not) to make sure I have weighed a few different options.

Edit: Just in case it isn't clear, I would like to create documentation of the summery comments in my C# code. Visual Studio exports this to XML already. Tools like doxygen inspects the code files them self. I want to convert these comments to Word docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html). It can generate various formats, including RTF, of the summary XML comments.

Comment: you know I looked at VSdocman a few times and am sad to say I missed that it output RTF files... Thank you.

Comment: Just for information, as of version 6.2 VSdocman can generate also DOCX format directly (I'm one of its developers).

Answer (score 0):

The code documentation is XML, right? [This fellow](http://news.oreilly.com/2008/08/importing-xml-documents-into-w.html) says that you can **open an XML document in Word** by choosing "open with transform" from the Open dialog box. Apparently that prompts to you provide information that is then used to generate an XSLT. It seems like you could use this as the basis for your own XSLT if you want to persist it?

This [detailed article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx) about XML comments in Visual Studio also suggests using XSLT to display the XML on a web page. So, you could just as well import that XML into your Word document

Answer (score 0):

SoftArtisan's [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com) can programmatically create .doc and .docx files via a .NET API. It's pretty rad, check it out.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who built the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to generate code documentation (C#, .net4) to MS Word file (.doc, .docx). This is not because I think it is better, but because it is easier to version control when compared to a set of HTML docs.

You should generate the documentation in whatever format you think is most helpful for users of your software.

Your code is presumably in version control. You can generate the XML with the API help directly from the code, and you can generate the help file itself (with whatever tool, in whatever format) from this XML. These output files don't necessarily need to be in version control at all.

Comment: The reasoning for this is awkward. The the short version is i know the HTML docs are much better to use. However the export isn't for end users. The version controlling is part of a process set by a customer...

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Don't forget that if you only need to add the docs to version control once for each release, you could just import the HTML into Word manually.